# How to return posts AND woo commerce products to same array?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, posts, product

I have a website which is currently pulling post_thumbnail images from woo commerce products in the 'homepage-carousel' product category:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'product_cat' => 'homepage-carousel' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

I want to also be able to pull in `post_thumbnail` images from regular posts in the `homepage-carousel` category.

How to add both types of post to the `$args` array?

Answer (score 2):

You can put an array inside the [`post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) key, just like this:

```
'post_type' => array('product','post')
```

Comment: Thats great but i'm getting the same result as before. Probably because the regular posts don't have a 'product_cat' they would have a 'category i guess. Is there a way to add something to the effect of:
'product_cat' => 'homepage-carousel' or 'category' => 'homepage-carousel'?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood you well. You have 2 types of products (i mean 2 post types)? and both of these products have their own categories? You might want to take a look at the tax_query (http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) parameter you can supply to your wp_query.